# Why does pandas change the index value in this example?

Tags: pandas, indexing

First we create a raw dataset with MultiIndex-

```
In [166]: import numpy as np; import pandas as pd 

In [167]: data_raw = pd.DataFrame([ 
     ...: {'frame': 1, 'face': np.NaN, 'lmark': np.NaN, 'x': np.NaN, 'y': np.NaN}, 
     ...: {'frame': 197, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 1, 'x': 969, 'y': 737}, 
     ...: {'frame': 197, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 2, 'x': 969, 'y': 740}, 
     ...: {'frame': 197, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 3, 'x': 970, 'y': 744}, 
     ...: {'frame': 197, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 4, 'x': 972, 'y': 748}, 
     ...: {'frame': 197, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 5, 'x': 973, 'y': 752}, 
     ...: {'frame': 300, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 1, 'x': 745, 'y': 367},  
     ...: {'frame': 300, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 2, 'x': 753, 'y': 411},  
     ...: {'frame': 300, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 3, 'x': 759, 'y': 455}, 
     ...: {'frame': 301, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 1, 'x': 741, 'y': 364},   
     ...: {'frame': 301, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 2, 'x': 746, 'y': 408},   
     ...: {'frame': 301, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 3, 'x': 750, 'y': 452}]).set_index(['frame', 'face', 'lmark'])
```

Next we calculate the z-scores for each `lmark` -

```
In [168]: ((data_raw - data_raw.mean(level='lmark')).abs()) / data_raw.std(level='lmark')            
Out[168]: 
                         x         y
frame face lmark                    
1     NaN  NaN         NaN       NaN
197   0.0  1.0    1.154565  1.154672
           2.0    1.154260  1.154665
           3.0    1.153946  1.154654
           4.0         NaN       NaN
           5.0         NaN       NaN
300   0.0  1.0    0.561956  0.570343
           2.0    0.549523  0.569472
           3.0    0.540829  0.568384
301   0.0  1.0    0.592609  0.584329
           2.0    0.604738  0.585193
           3.0    0.613117  0.586270
```

The index values don't change, as expected.
Now we filter out records where `lmark` > 3 -

```
In [170]: data_filtered = data_raw.loc[(slice(None), slice(None), [np.NaN, slice(3)]),:]

In [171]: data_filtered                                                                          
Out[171]: 
                      x      y
frame face lmark              
1     NaN  NaN      NaN    NaN
197   0.0  1.0    969.0  737.0
           2.0    969.0  740.0
           3.0    970.0  744.0
300   0.0  1.0    745.0  367.0
           2.0    753.0  411.0
           3.0    759.0  455.0
301   0.0  1.0    741.0  364.0
           2.0    746.0  408.0
           3.0    750.0  452.0
```

and recalculate the z-scores -

```
In [172]: ((data_filtered - data_filtered.mean(level='lmark')).abs()) / data_filtered.std(level='lmark')                                                                                       
Out[172]: 
                         x         y
frame face lmark                    
1     NaN  1.0         NaN       NaN
197   0.0  1.0    1.154565  1.154672
           2.0    1.154260  1.154665
           3.0    1.153946  1.154654
300   0.0  1.0    0.561956  0.570343
           2.0    0.549523  0.569472
           3.0    0.540829  0.568384
301   0.0  1.0    0.592609  0.584329
           2.0    0.604738  0.585193
           3.0    0.613117  0.586270
```

Why has the value of the first record's `lmark` index changed from `NaN` to `1.0`?

Answer (score 1):

I think it seems bug.

Solution is use [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html):

```
data_filtered.index = data_filtered.index.remove_unused_levels()
a = ((data_filtered - data_filtered.mean(level='lmark')).abs()) / data_filtered.std(level='lmark')
print (a)
                         x         y
frame face lmark                    
1     NaN  NaN         NaN       NaN
197   0.0  1.0    1.154565  1.154672
           2.0    1.154260  1.154665
           3.0    1.153946  1.154654
300   0.0  1.0    0.561956  0.570343
           2.0    0.549523  0.569472
           3.0    0.540829  0.568384
301   0.0  1.0    0.592609  0.584329
           2.0    0.604738  0.585193
           3.0    0.613117  0.586270
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response. In preparation to file a bug report, I cloned and installed the master branch from https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas. Then I repeated the steps to reproduce the bug. When I executed `data_filtered = data_raw.loc[(slice(None), slice(None), [np.NaN, slice(3)]),:]`, I now receive an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`. Any idea what that means?

Comment: @user2309803 - Hard question, for me selecting i npandas `0.23.1` not working too, it return same values. seems some problem with selecting by missing values. I test your solution by `data_filtered = data_raw.groupby(level=0).head(3)`

Comment: Issue created https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/33042